# Computing this conditional expectation?

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-distributions

Consider two random variables $X_1$,$X_2$ *iid* from a cdf $G$ on $[0,b]$. Consider also some concave function $f(.)$  with inverse $\phi(.)$ over $[0,b]$ such that $f(x)\leq x$, $\forall x\in [0,b]$.

Let $Z=\min\{X_1,X_2\}$ or equivalently $Z^{(2)}$ be the second-highest order statistic of $X_1,X_2$, I would like to compute the following conditional expectation:
$$E[f(Z)|f(X_1)=t]=E[Z|\phi(t)=X_1]$$or equivalently $$E[f(Z^{(2)})|f(X_1)=t]=E[Z^{(2)}|\phi(t)=X_1]$$

I'd like to show that whether $E[f(Z)|f(X_1)=t]$ is $>t$, $=t$ or $<t$, but I've no clue about how to compute this expectation first (I am not a probabilist).

If we let W(z) to be the cdf of Z then at a first glance is it correct to write that:

$$E[Z^{(2)}|X_1=\phi(t)]=\int_{0}^{\phi(t)}z\frac{dW(z)}{G(\phi(t)}$$ or am I missing something?

Many thanks!

Comment: What is the meaning of $\phi$ in "... with inverse $\phi$ over $[0,b]$." ?

Comment: I mean that the function $f$ which is defined over the domain $[0,b]$ has an inverse function $\phi(.)=[f(.)]^{-1}$ which is strictly increasing over the same domain. This is to justify why I can write $E[f(Z)|f(X_1)=t]=E[Z|\phi(t)=X_1]$

Comment: You are justified in claiming that $\mathsf E[f(Z)\mid f(X_1)=t] = \mathsf E(f(Z)\mid \phi(t)=X_1]$, when the events $\{f(X_1)=t\}$ and $\{\phi(t)=X_1\}$ are identical.  What is the basis of claiming $\mathsf E[f(Z)\mid f(X_1)=t] = \mathsf E(Z \mid f(X_1)=t]$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is indeed a bijection on that interval $[0;b]$ and that $t$ is in the image of $f$ ; then we can partition on the event that one independent random variable is greater than the other when given that the first random variable is a set value.

$\begin{align}\mathsf E(f(\min(X_1,X_2))\mid f(X_1)=t) 
~=&~ \mathsf E(f(X_1)\mathbf 1_{X_2>X_1}\mid X_1=\phi(t)) +\mathsf E(f(X_2)\mathbf 1_{X_2\leqslant X_1}\mid X_1=\phi(t)) 
\\[1ex]
~=&~ f(\phi(t))\,\mathsf P(X_2>\phi(t)) +\mathsf E(f(X_2)\mathbf 1_{X_2\leqslant \phi(t)}) 
\\[1ex] =&~ t\,(1-G(\phi(t))+\int_{0}^{\phi(t)}f(x)\,G(\operatorname dx) \end{align}$

Comment: many thanks Graham, I didn't think about partitioning the events!  You're right, I realize that I've made a mistake in the setup of the question in that we have two different functions, $f$ which applies for the condition and another one $g$ defines over the same domain which applies to the $\min$ and such that $g(x)=x$. This is the justification of why we get: $$E[g(\min(X_1,X_2))|f(X_1)=t]=E[\min(X_1,X_2)|\phi(t)=X_1]$$